# Deploying Spark-Java to CentOS server

Tags: spark-java

What is the best way to deploy Spark-Java onto my CentOs server, I want to make it production ready...

I am reading through the documentation on Spark-Java, paying close attention to the section labeled "Other web server" but it's pretty light by way of instructions...

[image]

So here are the steps that I am thinking (and please add or remove steps that I do not need)...

1. Spin up CentOs instance (pretty obvious)
2. Install Jetty - follow the steps on [this page](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-jetty-web-server-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html)
3. Clone repo onto my instance
4. Create my jar file
   `jar cf myfile.jar *.class`
5. Execute jar
   `java -jar myfile.jar`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want to install Jetty although you have an embedded Jetty inside Spark?

Comment: Actually, I was debating that also...my original thought was to install TomCat and run Spark off of that...but I wasn't sure if that would slow Spark down or not...

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance of Jetty vs Tomcat. I used Tomcat and it was pretty simple to have my Spark app up and running. The steps are (without going into details): install and run Tomcat --> deploy your webapp --> That's it. I think you should start and if you encounter any problem, you can publish a more specific question here.

Comment: sweet!! - I will do that...